# Beacon With Local Notification

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I am working with Beacon implementation in IOS. When someone enter into the Beacon region I used to send the local notification "Welcome Message" to the Beacon enabled app..

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    if(state == CLRegionStateInside) {
        NSLog(@"locationManager didDetermineState INSIDE for %@", region.identifier);

        // Create a local notification, and set up sounds
        UILocalNotification* notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        notification.alertBody = @"Welcome";
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
    }
    else if(state == CLRegionStateOutside) {
        NSLog(@"locationManager didDetermineState OUTSIDE for %@", region.identifier);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"locationManager didDetermineState OTHER for %@", region.identifier);
    }
}
```

I have added the local notification inside this delegate, but its not getting triggered.

Comment: then show the code because it works fine in general :)

Comment: I have added this in App delegate

Comment: ios8? did you register the userNotificationSettings?

Comment: Yes. Inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: I suggest you to first check the local notification..

Comment: its fine its not calling that delegate itself...

Comment: I enabled the background app refresh its just start working...

Answer (score 0):

Could you please post how you are initialising your CLRegion and which beacons are you working with.

I Suggest you should go for Estimote Beacons(estimote.com)

They provide you with Estimote SDK which is a wrapper over CLregionManager and Local notifies when user comes in or goes out of beacon region.

Also they have very good developer support and community.

Hope that helps you.